# Is it possible to detect user's activity/motion on a web app?

Tags: google-chrome, activity-recognition, cmmotionmanager, fitness

I am making a fitness-related web app and want the ability to detect various activities like cycling, running, walking, etc via a browser on a mobile device.

I understand there are CMMotionActivity and Activity Recognition APIs for iOS and Android respectively but is it possible to detect activities via a browser? Any leads?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Sensor_APIs

Comment: @IłyaBursov thanks for your reply. I have checked the link you provided. It does seem to provide access to data from various sensors in a device but what I am actually after is Activity Transition API like this one. https://developers.google.com/location-context/activity-recognition

Do you believe something like this can be done using the APIs you referred to earlier?